# GNU Parallel waits for n jobs before starting

Tags: shell-script, gnu-parallel

Im trying to use GNU parallel on a script, and i noticed that it only starts to output, after -jX X jobs

```bsh
# Only spawns cat after 100 seconds
(echo a; sleep 100) | parallel -j1 --lb cat

# Starts instantly
(echo a; echo a; sleep 100) | parallel -j1 --lb cat
```

The first job needs to be launched before the others (because it would define the other jobs as parallel pipe the output to another script), but parallel is waiting for 3 more jobs

Is there a way to change this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 20181222 or later.

```
# Spawns a instantly
(echo a; sleep 100) | parallel -j1 --lb cat

# Starts a and b instantly, outputs a immediately, b after 100 sec
(echo a; echo b; sleep 100) | parallel -j1 --lb cat

# Starts a and b instantly, outputs a and b immediately (but output may be mixed)
(echo a; echo b; sleep 100) | parallel -j1 --lb cat
```